# $(Z_n)_{n\ge0}:=(X_{2n+1})_{n\ge0}$ Markov chain given $(X_n)_{n\ge0}$ is a Markov chain?

Tags: markov-chains

Given a markov chain $(X_n)_{n\ge0}$ with transition matrix $P$ I just proved that $(Z_n)_{n\ge0}:=(X_{kn})_{n\ge0}$ is a Markov chain with transition matrix $P^k$, $k\ge1$.

Does this also work for $(Z_n)_{n\ge0}:=(X_{2n+1})_{n\ge0}$?

In case $(Z_n)_{n\ge0}:=(X_{2n+1})_{n\ge0}$ isn't a Markov chain: why not?

And in case it is, how can I express its transition matrix using $P$?

Comment: If $\{X_n\}$ is a homogeneous Markov chain the $\{X_{2n}\}$ and $\{X_{2n-1}\}$ are both Markov chains with transition matrix $P^{2}$.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Is the proof for $\{X_{2n-1}\}$ analogous to the proof for $\{X_{2n}\}$? (using the definition of two step transition probabilities as in example 3 here: http://www2.ece.rochester.edu/~gmateosb/ECE440/Midterm/practice_midterm_solutions.pdf ).

And lets say the state space of $X_n$ is $I=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and its initial disstribution is $\lambda$. Does it change for  $\{X_{2n-1}\}$, $\{X_{2n}\}$?

Comment: The two cases are similar.

Comment: Do $\lambda$ and/or $I$ change?